# Summing totals to an edit text output and preventing negatives

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parsing, user-interface

I have been stuck, regrettably, in a simple math problem.
I am creating a coffee application, as seen below, that takes the "Quantity" and multiplies it by the price to create a sub-total for each drink drink. It will then take all sub-totals from the drinks and add them together for the output at the bottom which would be updated automatically.

[image: drink Menu]

I have worked on the code to add or subtract from the 0 (I still can't figure out a way to prevent it from going below 0, if anyone has an idea, help is appreciated).
I have it so that the first 2 buttons (in pink) work right now for Espresso and Macchiato.

**Here is my Java file**

```
package com.example.cofeeshop;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class DrinkMenu extends Activity {
EditText quantity, quantity2, total;

Button button, plus1, minus1, plus2, minus2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drinkmenu);
    addListenerOnButton();

    // area for the espresso
    plus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    minus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    // area for the macchiato
    plus2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    minus2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    quantity2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    //subtotal for espresso
    //subtotal for macchiato

    total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);

    plus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V){

            String numb1 = quantity.getText().toString();

            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numb1);
            int inum1 = num1+1;
            quantity.setText(Integer.toString(inum1));
        }
    });//plus1 button
    minus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String numb1 = quantity.getText().toString();
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numb1);
            int inum1 = num1-1;
            quantity.setText(Integer.toString(inum1));

        }
    });//minus1 button

    plus2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V){

            String numb2 = quantity2.getText().toString();

            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numb2);
            int inum2 = num2+1;
            quantity2.setText(Integer.toString(inum2));
        }
    });//plus2 button
    minus2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String numb2 = quantity2.getText().toString();
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numb2);
            int inum2 = num2-1;
            quantity2.setText(Integer.toString(inum2));

        }
    });//minus2 button
    // Here is where I think I should place the sub-total multiplied by the prices
    // and will be out put to the total = espresso_sub_total*espress_price + 
    // macchiato_sub_total*macchiato_price + and so on for the other drinks

  }

}
```

Now, It may be imperative that I set my Total price to a Text View rather than Edit Text also, thoughts?

So after implementing ideas from both users @useruser3249477 and @Shobhit I have gotten the numbers to stop going below 0 and above 10, but then I tried to add the total together in the Total area of '0'. I have updated code below for both java and the xml file. It crashes as I press the '+' button.

**updated Java source code**:

```
package com.example.cofeeshop;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrinkMenu extends Activity {
EditText quantity, quantity2;
//TextView total;
Button button, plus1, minus1, plus2, minus2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drinkmenu);
    addListenerOnButton();

    // area for the espresso
    plus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    minus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    // area for the macchiato
    plus2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    minus2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    quantity2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    //espresso-sub-total
    //macchiato-sub-total

    //total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);


    plus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V){

            String numb1 = quantity.getText().toString();

            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numb1);
            int inum1 = num1+1;
            if (inum1 > 10) return;
            quantity.setText(Integer.toString(inum1));
        }
    });//plus1 button
    minus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String numb1 = quantity.getText().toString();
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numb1);
            int inum1 = num1-1;
            if (inum1 < 0) return;
            quantity.setText(Integer.toString(inum1));

        }
    });//minus2 button

    plus2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V){

            String numb2 = quantity2.getText().toString();

            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numb2);
            int inum2 = num2+1;
            if (inum2 > 10) return;
            quantity2.setText(Integer.toString(inum2));
        }
    });//plus1 buttons
    minus2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String numb2 = quantity2.getText().toString();
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numb2);
            int inum2 = num2-1;
            if (inum2 < 0) return;
            quantity2.setText(Integer.toString(inum2));

        }
    });

//    double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(numb1);
    // Here is where I think I should place the sub-total multiplied by the prices
    // and will be out put to the total = num1*3;


    final TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            // Remove previous price of these items
            int count = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());
            // Assume total holds text of an integer
            int curTotal = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString());
            int newTotal = curTotal - count*3;
            total.setText(newTotal);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            // Add the new items price
            int count = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());
            // Assume total holds text of an integer
            int curTotal = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString());
            int newTotal = curTotal + count*3;
            total.setText(newTotal);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
    };

    quantity.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    quantity2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
//order button code that is useless to this question.
}
```

**Here is my updated XML file that is updated:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Drinks:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/orderbtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/orderbtn"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Quantity:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Espresso"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Macchiato"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Con Panna"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Latte"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text=" 0"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button12"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText6"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText7"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText5"
    android:background="#ffff45df"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="$3.00 per drink"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="$3.00 per drink"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="$3.00 per drink"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="$3.00 per drink"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="$3.00 per drink"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Americano"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/orderbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonround"
    android:text="Order"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/orderbtn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/orderbtn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Total:  $"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are some of the errors coming out.

E/AndroidRuntime(369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(369): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0// seems to be here

E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)

Comment: And you want the total to be set automatically?

Comment: @user3249477 Yes, I do, thank you for reminding me to put that in. That is important!

Answer (score 1):

A simple check will prevent negative values (using the buttons):

```
minus2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String numb2 = quantity2.getText().toString();
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numb2);
        int inum2 = num2-1;
        if (inum2 < 0) return;
        quantity2.setText(Integer.toString(inum2));
    }
});
```

To prevent manually entering negative values, you can set `android:digits="0123456789"` as @ShobhitPuri suggested.

Then for the total you'll need to set TextWatchers:

```
final EditText total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            // Remove previous price of these items
            int count = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());
            // Assume total holds text of an integer
            int curTotal = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString());
            int newTotal = curTotal - count*3;
            total.setText(newTotal);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            // Add the new items price
            int count = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());
            // Assume total holds text of an integer
            int curTotal = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString());
            int newTotal = curTotal + count*3;
            total.setText(newTotal);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
    };

// Now set the TextWatcher on every count EditText
// If you have different prices, you'll need multiple TextWatchers
quantity1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
quantity2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

...
```

Comment: Ok, that non-zero part helped me out a lot. I do have one question, so you think it is good to have that total '0' part be a edit text then?

Comment: @GaryC no. It should be a TextView.

Comment: So I've updated it so that the two drinks do not go below 0 or above 10, and I've changed it so that the total '0' area is a textview, but can I manipulate text view in java?

Comment: @GaryC sure you can. You can set the text in the same way as you did with the `EditText`.

Comment: I have updated the code with what you gave me and included the textview7 (the spot where the 0 is next to Total: $) and when I press the '+' button it crashes, I think I am missing something in my thinking/code. I posted the new code

Comment: @GaryC probably a problem with layouts. Try debugging it yourself for a change :)

Answer (score 0):

> "I still can't figure out a way to prevent it from going below 0"

- One way is you can add `android:digits="0123456789"` to your `EditText`'s in xml file. This will prevent user from entering anything but these numbers.
- One other way is to do a check in the `onClickListener`. In this you'll need to check for all the `EditText`'s values using `ed.getText()` and then check if its integer and is in the range acceptable by you.
- One more way is to use [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) on `EditText`. You can listen you what is being inputted there. You can make a check for condition when its less than 0 or an invalid character has been put in. (Its good to limit the keyboard so as to prevent garbage entry at the first place).

Comment: You can still set it to a negative value using the buttons.

Comment: @Shobhit I see what you did there.